# unable to deploy spring boot app on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I was trying to deploy spring boot micro-service on the tomcat server but was unable to get any response. The url was showing 404 error then I decided to go from very basic so I created a simple spring boot project with [Spring Boot Initializer](https://start.spring.io/). There I choose

- war as packaging.
- java version 16 (as I only have this on my machine).
- Added Spring Web dependency.

With this setting spring initializer automatically added necessary stuff like `war packaging`, `tomcat dependency`, `spring web dependency` and also created `ServletInitializer` class for me.
After that I opened the downloading project in `netbeans 12` and made just a few changes i.e.

- Added main class in the `pom.xml` file with `<start-class>` tag and annotated main class with `@RestController` and exposed 1 endpoint which return simple string.
- Then from the project's main folder I ran the command `mvn package` also tried `mvn clean install` as deployment with the 1st command was unsuccessful.

Here are my configuration
**Environment Variables:**
System Variables

- CATALINA_HOME: `D:\Inzimam Tariq\apache-tomcat-10.0.10`.
- JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2`
- Relevent values in Path Variable: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`, `D:\Inzimam Tariq\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin`, and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin`.

**User Variable**

- MAVEN_HOME: `D:\Inzimam Tariq\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin`.

I'm using windows 10 64-bit. Tomcat manager shows the app as deployed but when I click on that it shows `404`. My JDK folder does not show JRE folder so I searched over internet and found that Java does not include JRE now. I also tried to rename my war file to the project name as some articles suggested that i.e. `abc.war` from `abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` but still error is the same.

Please can someone point me to the right direction? Regards

Comment: Try to name it `ROOT.war`. Does that work?

Comment: Do you have an index page in your application? Did you check tomcat logs (server and error)?

Comment: @dan1st it does not work with `ROOT.war` either.

Comment: @aksappy its a rest api app so it has a public endpoint not an index page

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz let me try tomcat 9

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks its working on tomcat 9

Answer (score -1):

After Deploying your project war file in Tomcat, try to make the following changes in your POM.xml file. Then restart your tomcat. Probably it will work.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>    
                        <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>         
                        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
                </dependency>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```